# Google Assistance Vs. Api.ai

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I recently started studying Google Assistance. I am trying to understand how it works under the hood and found following screenshot from Google i/o 16.

[image: Google Assistance Diagram]

Based on my understanding, NLP, which resides in Google Assistance portion, handles natural language processing and realize what needs to be done in order to fulfill user request.

But when I read description on api.ai, it is described as Natural Language Understanding (NLU). I believe NLU is part of NLP.

Why do we need two NLUs? What is api.ai really doing in the diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the way I understand how things work for Actions on Google. Take it with however many grains of salt you like.

First there is the phrase that kicks off the process. For example "OK, Google talk to 'my app'" or "OK, Google ask 'my app' 'my query'". Clearly the Actions platform - whatever that is - needs to understand this phrase, yes? "OK, Google" might introduce a voice search intended for Google itself or it could dispatch an Action or it could be a request to send an email etc. Further IF it dispatches an Action it needs to be run it and pass it a query if it is present. So AoG does need require some amount of understanding to get the ball rolling.

But once an Action is dispatched AoG's job has more to do with recognition than understanding. At every turn of the conversation it is posting the text of what it hears - fairly uncritically - to an Action for it to understand. The Action then returns text and again, without the need to understand the response it passes the text through the speech synthesizer (or TTS engine if you like).

Now the Action is required to understand its own grammar and deal with the phrases however it requires. Some Actions - those built with the Actions SDK - do their own understanding with proprietary NLUs. Others use Dialog Flow (formerly known as API.AI) to understand the text. Here Dialog Flow is like a shim or a middle man that sits between a 3rd party Action and the AoG platform.

Comment: Hmm, Okay. So what you are saying is basically initially Google try to understand intention of the request. Then depends on the intention, it invokes Dialog Flow to handle the action? Hence, Dialog Flow has its own NLU. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that's right. Just keep in mind that using Dialog Flow is a choice that most developers make at design time. It is a relatively painless way to get code to "understand" natural language. But if you want complete and total control over the natural language understanding you can use the Actions SDK and go your own way. It is much more work.

Comment: Thank you! This greatly helped me!